# Help with installing Cheese from package (12.04 LTS)

Tags: 12.04, installation, package-management, cheese

I need help with installing Cheese 3.8.3 from the package I downloaded on the website. The instructions attached with the file aren't clear enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the latest package *INSTALL* file indicates that you simply need to `./configure; make; make install' to get it working. Here's a step by step how to install it:

1. Download the package
2. Unpack it
3. In the unpacked destination with terminal execute:

   ./configure

then

```
make
```

then

```
make install
```

this should install cheese :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new with this. :c Could you explain on how to do those steps in a little more detail? Thank you for responding!